# Android: How to take a photo and view the photo, save the photo as a JPEG?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, curl, android-camera-intent

I am wondering is there a way of taking a photo with a Camera `intent` in android and saving the photo as a JPEG and to then insert the photos path within a variable, which can be then inserted within a cURL command?

What I have so far is the camera taking a photo but it saves it to gallery, but I don't know how.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package project.com;


import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "fyp.com.pastec_currency_recognition";
    final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    // Called when the user taps the Camera Button
    public void cameraAccess(View view) {
        //This function invokes an intent to capture a photo
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivity(takePictureIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

**And XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:onClick="cameraAccess"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I know there is a lot of tutorials out there for taking a photo and saving a image but I've found none that allow you to get the path of the photo and store it in a variable to use in a Java converted cURL command.

Comment: where are you saving the image? to the sd card? to the device? pretty simple actually.... do it in steps. find a tutorial for taking the picture..... then find a tutorial for saving the image...then find a tutorial for getting the path of a picture. all of this is out there.

Comment: @DroiDev I want to save it to where ever it is easiest to retrieve the path of it from?

Comment: what is your end goal with this service?

Comment: I'm attempting to make an app which takes a photo and attaches the photos path of where its saved to a cURL command in order to execute the cURL command involving the photo

Comment: sooooo, you need it for the API. why not store the image in a server/DB and not on the device?

Comment: @DroiDev how would you go about doing that if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Firebase or ParseServer....

Comment: @DroiDev Thank you